# units for rings in haskell in Num or Rational

Tags: haskell, zero

The Num class of haskell allows for quite general algebraic structures and looks like it's intended to be used to make rings. When speaking of a ring though, it's convenient to be able to explicitly mention its additional and multiplicative units - maybe Num.Zero and Num.One - is there such a thing to Num, another class that includes units or some other way that this is done?

Answer (score 17):

If your instance of `Num` is a ring, one expects `fromInteger` to be a ring homomorphism and thus `0` and `1` will just work.  This may not always hold.  `Num` predates typeclasses having algebraic laws be the norm.  Also, unfortunetly, many instances of `Num` are not rings (such as floating point numbers).

`Num` is not really a ring structure, since it also has "other stuff" like `abs`, `signum` and the (hopefully) ring homomorphism `fromInteger`.  I tend to think of it as "probably ring-ish with some other stuff."

Example: the ring of [Gaussian rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational)

```
import Data.Ratio
import Data.Complex

type GaussianRational = Complex Rational

zero :: GaussianRational 
zero = 0

one :: GaussianRational
one = 1
```

EDIT: Since Z is initial in Ring, the idea of using `fromInteger` this way actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: that's a good suggestion! - as long as one takes care to make fromInteger 0 return the zero and fromInteger 1 return a 1 it will work just fine!

Comment: @simonize The numeric literal `1` is already `fromIntegral 1`.

Answer (score 4):

The entire [`algebra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebra) package is devoted to these kinds of purposes. For instance, we have

```
class (Rig r, Rng r) => Ring r
```

and the supporting cast

```
class (Semiring r, Unital r, Monoidal r) => Rig r
class (Group r, Semiring r) => Rng r
class Multiplicative r => Unital r
class (Additive r, Abelian r, Multiplicative r) => Semiring r
class (LeftModule Integer r, RightModule Integer r, Monoidal r) => Group r
class (LeftModule Natural m, RightModule Natural m) => Monoidal m
class (Semiring r, Additive m) => RightModule r m
class (Semiring r, Additive m) => LeftModule r m
class Multiplicative r
class Additive r
class Additive r => Abelian r
```

which is at least one way to build up a ring. If you're doing highly general algebra then `algebra` might be worth it, but most libraries just expect `Num`.